# Can we use Google Android in-App purchase in Android apps published on Samsung Store?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am in the process of publishing my android game and it would be released on Samsung store. I am using Android in App purchase system inside my Game, but I am not sure if Samsung allows using it or does it require using its Samsung Plasma Purchase system only ?

Comment: Did you found solution?

Answer (score 1):

For samsung app Store you need to use Plasma....

for more ref. visit

http://developer.samsung.com/distribute/monetization

http://developer.samsung.com/android/technical-docs/In-App-Purchase-using-Plasma-in-Android

This may help you

Comment: So, is there no way I can use android in-app purchase system in samsung app store ? Only Plasma is the option ?

Comment: On the page you referred, http://developer.samsung.com/distribute/monetization , It is mentioned at the end : "Alternative revenue collection methods do exist, for instance set password protected content could be sold or given away via alternative distribution channels"

Does that mean we can use android inApp purchase as the alternate payment system ?